How to upload a large dataset (10M) records to Hybris
We have to load a large dataset (10 million records) in a SAP Hybris database.
Trying to do this standard framework components, like Impex, or Hybis data model are not viable options as it is turning out to be extremely slow (near an hour for ~30K records).
What is the best way to opitmize such large data upload to Hybris database?
We do not have direct access to database.
Has somebody done this before? Thanks in advancefor any pointers.
Regards
Das

Did you try oData?

Hi @mkysoft thank you for the response. No it is not tried yet. Will that be better in this case? can you please provide bit more pointers.

I haven't try it for load huge data but it has batch mode option. Maybe it will get better performcen.

Try using legacy mode when impex, it is still slow, but better without using it. It will skip all interceptors though, so make sure the data don't need any transformation by the interceptor. And if your server can handle it, increase the maximum threads number (2x CPU)
